# In Flutter, How can I change TextFormField validation error message style?

Tags: flutter

I want to set a bigger font size for error message validation in **TextFormField** but I don't know how.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

For this you have to use `InputDecoration`

```dart
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    errorStyle: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 16.0,
    ),
  ),
  ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to change the error message position. or if i can access the error message on validation i can add text widget and show it anywhere i want.

Comment: I doubt it can be done without creating a custom widget

Comment: Yeah Thanks, I'm showing the error message below the text input border. as default as material widgets. Its seems like fine for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TextFormField's property 'decoration' like that.

```
TextFormField( 
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    errorStyle: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 15,
      color: Colors.red,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
    ),
  ),
)
```